# How to solve Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH,mode 040777 warning on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777`

I've tried these two commands after searching for solutions on Stackexchange, but it didn't work for me. It still shows me the warning which I've pasted above.

```
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local

sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin
```

How do I fix this warning message? I'm running OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Learn to read the error messages closely.

```
Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH
```

Note it's not saying `/usr/local`.

To confirm this diagnosis, use

```
 ls -ld /usr
 drwxrwxrwx  14 ownerID  groupID     4096 Dec 10  2010 /usr
 #-------^-  is the world-writeable  part
```

As you know, you can fix it with

```
 sudo chmod 755 /usr
```

**Edit**

Folks, See my scripted solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570203/unix-installer-cant-find-path-to-file-even-though-im-entering-the-exact-path/29571473#29571473).

Comment: with `sudo chmod 755 /usr` it crashed my permission fully. exception: `owned by uid 0`.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this by using Disk Utility to repair disk permissions.

Open the Disk Utility application and select the disk your system is installed on. Then you can select "Repair Disk Permissions" from the First Aid tab. Repair will take a couple of minutes

Comment: Going by the amount of permissions it found botched (which I promptly fixed) I'm going to be doing this quite frequently. Thanks!

Comment: is that operation now just part of First Aid, i couldnt find it in Disk Utility.

Comment: WOW.. This helped me to repair **ALL PERMISSIONS** on every file!! Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on MacOS High Sierra so to fix permissions I had to follow the instructions here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

Comment: @Cyborg : An old topic here. Are  you still using `Disk Utility`? Which OS platform has this? Thanks for any info and good luck!

Comment: @shellter I was using MacOS, all OS X has Disk Utility Application. You can link external Hard Drives to OS X also and use this App.

Answer (score 2):

Executing the following worked for me on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan

`sudo chmod o-w /usr/local`

The error occured when loading a vagrant as follows;

`vagrant status
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
ls -dal /usr/local/
drwxrwxrwx  10 root  wheel  340 Sep  9 15:05 /usr/local/`

After running the chmod mentioned above.

`ls -dal /usr/local/
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  wheel  340 Sep  9 15:05 /usr/local/`

Which solved the problem.