# Unix Installer can't find path to file even though I'm entering the exact path

Tags: unix, installation

I'm trying to modify an existing script that updates Flash but the installer will not work.

I keep getting the following error.

installer: Error the package path specified was invalid: '/Volumes/Flash Player/Install Adobe Flash Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Player Install Manager'.

It also does not work if I modify it to say include.pkg at the end of the filepath.

Here is the rest of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script to download and install Flash Player.
# Only works on Intel systems.
#

dmgfile="flash.dmg"
volname="Flash"
logfile="FlashUpdateScript.log"
echo "Updating Flash player…"
# Are we running on Intel?
if [ '`/usr/bin/uname -p`'="i386" -o '`/usr/bin/uname -p`'="x86_64" ]; then
    # Get the latest version of Flash Player available from Adobe's About Flash page.
    latestver=`/usr/bin/curl -s http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ | sed -n '/Safari/,/<\/tr/s/[^>]*>\([0-9].*\)<.*/\1/p'`
    # Get the version number of the currently-installed Flash Player, if any.
    if [ -e "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin" ]; then
    currentinstalledver=`/usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Flash\ Player.plugin/Contents/version CFBundleShortVersionString`
    else
    currentinstalledver="none"
    fi
    echo "Installed version:                 $currentinstalledver"
    echo "Currently last version to install: $latestver"
# Compare the two versions, if they are different of Flash is not present then download and install the new version.
if [ "${currentinstalledver}" != "${latestver}" ]; then
    echo "UPDATING…"
    /bin/echo "`date`: Current Flash version: ${currentinstalledver}" >> ${logfile}
    /bin/echo "`date`: Available Flash version: ${latestver}" >> ${logfile}
    /bin/echo "`date`: Downloading newer version." >> ${logfile}
    /usr/bin/curl http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player_osx.dmg -o flash.dmg
    /bin/echo "`date`: Mounting installer disk image." >> ${logfile}
    /usr/bin/hdiutil detach $(/bin/df | /usr/bin/grep Flash | awk '{print $1}') -quiet
    /usr/bin/hdiutil attach flash.dmg -nobrowse -quiet
    /bin/echo "`date`: Installing..." >> ${logfile}
    /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /Volumes/Flash\ Player/Install\ Adobe\ Flash\ Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe\ Flash\ Player\ Install\ Manager -target /
    /bin/sleep 10
    /bin/echo "`date`: Unmounting installer disk image." >> ${logfile}
    /usr/bin/hdiutil detach $(/bin/df | /usr/bin/grep ${volname} | awk '{print $1}') -quiet
    /bin/sleep 10
    /bin/echo "`date`: Deleting disk image." >> ${logfile}
    /bin/rm ${dmgfile}
    newlyinstalledver=`/usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Flash\ Player.plugin/Contents/version CFBundleShortVersionString`
        if [ "${latestver}" = "${newlyinstalledver}" ]; then
            /bin/echo "`date`: SUCCESS: Flash has been updated to version ${newlyinstalledver}" >> ${logfile}
            echo "SUCCESS: Flash has been updated to version ${newlyinstalledver}"
        else
            /bin/echo "`date`: ERROR: Flash update unsuccessful, version remains at ${currentinstalledver}." >> ${logfile}
            /bin/echo "--" >> ${logfile}
            echo "ERROR: Flash update unsuccessful, version remains at ${currentinstalledver}."
        fi
    # If Flash is up to date already, just log it and exit.       
    else
        /bin/echo "`date`: Flash is already up to date, running ${currentinstalledver}." >> ${logfile}
        /bin/echo "--" >> ${logfile}
        echo "Flash is already up to date, running ${currentinstalledver}."
    fi
else
/bin/echo "`date`: ERROR: This script is for Intel Macs only." >> ${logfile}
echo "ERROR: This script is for Intel Macs only."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to confirm that each segment of the path has permissions that would allow you to write to that directory and any below it. Save the following script into a directory in your PATH (`/usr/local/bin` would be appropriate) OR save it into the `/tmp` dir and use it with a full path.

```
cat pathChecker.sh    
#!/bin/bash

path2chk="${@?usage:${0##*/} /path/to/check}"
if ! [[ -d "${path2chk}" ]] ; then
   echo "no directory access to ${path2chk}"
   echo "checking all elements anyway"
fi

echo "${path2chk}"\
| sed 's/\//\n/g' \
| while read pathElem ; do
    testPath="${testPath+${testPath}/}${pathElem}"
    #dbg echo "ls -ld \"$testPath\""
    ls -ld "$testPath"
done


chmod +x pathChecker.sh
pathChecker.sh '/Volumes/Flash Player/Install Adobe Flash Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Player Install Manager'
```

Should show listings like

```
drwxr-x-r-x ..... /Volumes
drwxr------ ..... /Volumes/Flash Player   # bzt!
. . . .
```

**Edit** Also see a more generic explanation of the problem here:

[How to solve Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH,mode 040777 warning on Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711249/how-to-solve-insecure-world-writable-dir-usr-in-path-mode-040777-warning-on-rub/26718467#26718467)

IHTH

Comment: Also, looking at your code, I would try `installer -pkg '/Volumes/Flash Player/Install Adobe....'`, although what you have looks right. Good luck.