# Get reason for permission denied due to traversed directory not executable

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, directory-traversal

I have a file `/a/b` that is readable by a user `A`. But `/a` does not provide executable permission by `A`, and thus the path `/a/b` cannot traverse through `/a`. For an arbitrarily long path, how would I determine the cause for not being able to access a given path due to an intermediate path not being accessible by the user?

Comment: you may find my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570203/unix-installer-cant-find-path-to-file-even-though-im-entering-the-exact-path/29571473#29571473 of  help (but not a direct solution). Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative answer to parsing the tree manually and pinpointing the error to a single row would be using namei tool.

```
namei -mo a/b/c/d
f: a/b/c/d
 drwxrw-rw- rasjani rasjani a
 drw-rwxr-x rasjani rasjani b
                        c - No such file or directory
```

This shows the whole tree structure and permissions up until the entry where the permission is denied.

Comment: This was something I didn't know about, and seems the most logical pre-existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something along like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PAR=${1}
PAR=${PAR:="."}
if ! [[ "${PAR:0:1}" == / || "${PAR:0:2}" == ~[/a-z] ]]
then
  TMP=`pwd`
  PAR=$(dirname ${TMP}/${PAR})
fi

cd $PAR 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  while [ ! -z "$PAR" ]; do
    PREV=$(readlink -f ${PAR})
    TMP=$(echo ${PAR}|awk -F\/ '{$NF=""}'1|tr ' ' \/)
    PAR=${TMP%/}
    cd ${PAR} 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      if [ -e ${PREV} ]; then
        ls -ld ${PREV}
      fi
      exit
    fi
  done
fi
```

Ugly but it would get the job done ..

So the idea is basicly that taking a parameter $1, if its not absolute directory, expand it to such and then drop the last element of the path and try to cd into it, if it fails, rince and repeat .. If it works, PREV would hold the last directory where user couldn't cd into, so print it out ..

Comment: Can you provide a reference indicating there is no superior alternative, or this is the conventional way to do this?

Comment: No idea about the superior alternative as this is also quite bad in sense it has string parsing which might fail.  Another alternative would be to do bottom to top iteration with find -type -d $PAR, grep the stderr for "Permission denied", grep that error against PAR to avoid other sub directories to show .. Would propably be prettier.

Comment: So, iterating is the key here as there's no other way AFAIK that can report if the access is prevented within the path leading to actual endpoint.  Using test -x||test -r checking maybe, but also that fails short in that it does not provide the information at which point in the path the access was denied ..

Comment: Thus, essentially, this sort of approach is just conventional way to reach the goal =)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I threw together.  I actually didn't look at rasjani's answer before writing this, but it uses the same concept where you take the exit status of the command.  Basically its going through all the directories (starting the farthest down the chain) and tries to `ls` them.  If the exit status is 0, then the `ls` succeeded, and it prints out the last dir that it couldn't `ls` (I'm not sure what would happen in some of the edge cases like where you can't access *anything*):

```
LAST=/a/b
while [ ! -z "$LAST" ] ; do
    NEXT=`echo "$LAST" | sed 's/[^\/]*$//' | sed 's/\/$//'`
    ls "$NEXT" 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then 
        echo "Can't access: $LAST"
        break
    fi
    LAST="$NEXT"
done
```

and I like putting stuff like this on one line just for fun:

```
LAST=/a/b; while [ ! -z "$LAST" ] ; do NEXT=`echo "$LAST" | sed 's/[^\/]*$//' | sed 's/\/$//'`; ls "$NEXT" 2> /dev/null > /dev/null; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "Can't access: $LAST"; break; fi; LAST="$NEXT"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I have below C program for you which does this. Below are the steps

1. Copy and save program as file.c.
2. Compile program with gcc file.c -o file
3. Execute it as ./file PATH

Assuming that you have a path as /a/b/c/d and you do not have permission for 'c' then output will be

```
  Given Path = /a/b/c/d

  No permission on = /a/b/c
```

For permission i am relying on "EACCES" error. Path length is assumed to 1024.

If you have any question please share.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <errno.h>

  #define MAX_LEN 1024

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    char path[MAX_LEN] = "/home/sudhansu/Test";
    int i = 0;
    char parse[MAX_LEN] = "";

    if(argc == 2)
    {
      strcpy(path, argv[1]);
      printf("\n\t\t Given Path = %s\n", path);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\n\t\t Usage : ./file PATH\n\n");
      return 0;
    }

    if(path[strlen(path)-1] != '/')
      strcat(path, "/");

    path[strlen(path)] = '\0';

    while(path[i])
    {
      if(path[i] == '/')
      {
        strncpy(parse, path, i+1);
        if(chdir(parse) < 0)
        {
          if(errno == EACCES)
          {
            printf("\t\t No permission on = [%s]\n", parse);
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      parse[i] = path[i];
      i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

Regards,
Sudhansu