# PHP Centos Can't write to file / create folder. But permissions looks okay

Tags: php, linux, permissions, centos

this is killing me for the past hours...
After 2 days of not using the php script now it refuses to write the file..
The issue is the following, we did an upgrade and now it won't append to a file, write a new file or create a directory as it says no permissions.

I tried to fix this and now the folder is owned by nginx:nginx, process is owned by nginx, the php script is owner by nginx and the .txt file too also php-fpm is  is owned by nginx, also in  visudo I added this line (To make you understand how much I'm sad)

> `nginx ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

I don't know what do to anymore...

> ***www.conf*** of **php-fpm**

```
            ; Start a new pool named 'www'.
            [www]

            ; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
            ; Valid syntaxes are:
            ;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
            ;                            a specific port;
            ;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
            ;                            specific port;
            ;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
            ; Note: This value is mandatory.
            listen = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

            ; Set listen(2) backlog. A value of '-1' means unlimited.
            ; Default Value: -1
            ;listen.backlog = -1

            ; List of ipv4 addresses of FastCGI clients which are allowed to connect.
            ; Equivalent to the FCGI_WEB_SERVER_ADDRS environment variable in the original
            ; PHP FCGI (5.2.2+). Makes sense only with a tcp listening socket. Each address
            ; must be separated by a comma. If this value is left blank, connections will be
            ; accepted from any ip address.
            ; Default Value: any
            listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

            ; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
            ; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
            ; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
            ; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
            ;                 mode is set to 0666
            listen.owner = nginx
            listen.group = nginx
            listen.mode = 0776

            ; Unix user/group of processes
            ; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
            ;       will be used.
            ; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
            user = nginx
            ; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
            group = nginx

            ; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
            ; Possible Values:
            ;   static  - a fixed number (pm.max_children) of child processes;
            ;   dynamic - the number of child processes are set dynamically based on the
            ;             following directives:
            ;             pm.max_children      - the maximum number of children that can
            ;                                    be alive at the same time.
            ;             pm.start_servers     - the number of children created on startup.
            ;             pm.min_spare_servers - the minimum number of children in 'idle'
            ;                                    state (waiting to process). If the number
            ;                                    of 'idle' processes is less than this
            ;                                    number then some children will be created.
            ;             pm.max_spare_servers - the maximum number of children in 'idle'
            ;                                    state (waiting to process). If the number
            ;                                    of 'idle' processes is greater than this
            ;                                    number then some children will be killed.
            ; Note: This value is mandatory.
            pm = dynamic

            ; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
            ; maximum number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'dynamic'.
            ; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
            ; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
            ; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
            ; CGI.
            ; Note: Used when pm is set to either 'static' or 'dynamic'
            ; Note: This value is mandatory.
            pm.max_children = 50

            ; The number of child processes created on startup.
            ; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
            ; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
            pm.start_servers = 5

            ; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
            ; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
            ; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
            pm.min_spare_servers = 5

            ; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
            ; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
            ; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
            pm.max_spare_servers = 35

            ; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
            ; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
            ; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
            ; Default Value: 0
            ;pm.max_requests = 500

            ; The URI to view the FPM status page. If this value is not set, no URI will be
            ; recognized as a status page. By default, the status page shows the following
            ; information:
            ;   accepted conn    - the number of request accepted by the pool;
            ;   pool             - the name of the pool;
            ;   process manager  - static or dynamic;
            ;   idle processes   - the number of idle processes;
            ;   active processes - the number of active processes;
            ;   total processes  - the number of idle + active processes.
            ; The values of 'idle processes', 'active processes' and 'total processes' are
            ; updated each second. The value of 'accepted conn' is updated in real time.
            ; Example output:
            ;   accepted conn:   12073
            ;   pool:             www
            ;   process manager:  static
            ;   idle processes:   35
            ;   active processes: 65
            ;   total processes:  100
            ; By default the status page output is formatted as text/plain. Passing either
            ; 'html' or 'json' as a query string will return the corresponding output
            ; syntax. Example:
            ;   http://www.foo.bar/status
            ;   http://www.foo.bar/status?json
            ;   http://www.foo.bar/status?html
            ; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
            ;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
            ;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
            ; Default Value: not set
            ;pm.status_path = /status

            ; The ping URI to call the monitoring page of FPM. If this value is not set, no
            ; URI will be recognized as a ping page. This could be used to test from outside
            ; that FPM is alive and responding, or to
            ; - create a graph of FPM availability (rrd or such);
            ; - remove a server from a group if it is not responding (load balancing);
            ; - trigger alerts for the operating team (24/7).
            ; Note: The value must start with a leading slash (/). The value can be
            ;       anything, but it may not be a good idea to use the .php extension or it
            ;       may conflict with a real PHP file.
            ; Default Value: not set
            ;ping.path = /ping

            ; This directive may be used to customize the response of a ping request. The
            ; response is formatted as text/plain with a 200 response code.
            ; Default Value: pong
            ;ping.response = pong

            ; The timeout for serving a single request after which the worker process will
            ; be killed. This option should be used when the 'max_execution_time' ini option
            ; does not stop script execution for some reason. A value of '0' means 'off'.
            ; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
            ; Default Value: 0
            ;request_terminate_timeout = 0

            ; The timeout for serving a single request after which a PHP backtrace will be
            ; dumped to the 'slowlog' file. A value of '0s' means 'off'.
            ; Available units: s(econds)(default), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
            ; Default Value: 0
            ;request_slowlog_timeout = 0

            ; The log file for slow requests
            ; Default Value: not set
            ; Note: slowlog is mandatory if request_slowlog_timeout is set
            slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log

            ; Set open file descriptor rlimit.
            ; Default Value: system defined value
            ;rlimit_files = 1024

            ; Set max core size rlimit.
            ; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
            ; Default Value: system defined value
            ;rlimit_core = 0

            ; Chroot to this directory at the start. This value must be defined as an
            ; absolute path. When this value is not set, chroot is not used.
            ; Note: chrooting is a great security feature and should be used whenever
            ;       possible. However, all PHP paths will be relative to the chroot
            ;       (error_log, sessions.save_path, ...).
            ; Default Value: not set
            ;chroot =

            ; Chdir to this directory at the start. This value must be an absolute path.
            ; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot
            ;chdir = /var/www

            ; Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, stdout and
            ; stderr will be redirected to /dev/null according to FastCGI specs.
            ; Default Value: no
            ;catch_workers_output = yes

            ; Limits the extensions of the main script FPM will allow to parse. This can
            ; prevent configuration mistakes on the web server side. You should only limit
            ; FPM to .php extensions to prevent malicious users to use other extensions to
            ; exectute php code.
            ; Note: set an empty value to allow all extensions.
            ; Default Value: .php
            ;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5

            ; Pass environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All $VARIABLEs are taken from
            ; the current environment.
            ; Default Value: clean env
            ;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
            ;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
            ;env[TMP] = /tmp
            ;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
            ;env[TEMP] = /tmp

            ; Additional php.ini defines, specific to this pool of workers. These settings
            ; overwrite the values previously defined in the php.ini. The directives are the
            ; same as the PHP SAPI:
            ;   php_value/php_flag             - you can set classic ini defines which can
            ;                                    be overwritten from PHP call 'ini_set'.
            ;   php_admin_value/php_admin_flag - these directives won't be overwritten by
            ;                                     PHP call 'ini_set'
            ; For php_*flag, valid values are on, off, 1, 0, true, false, yes or no.

            ; Defining 'extension' will load the corresponding shared extension from
            ; extension_dir. Defining 'disable_functions' or 'disable_classes' will not
            ; overwrite previously defined php.ini values, but will append the new value
            ; instead.

            ; Default Value: nothing is defined by default except the values in php.ini and
            ;                specified at startup with the -d argument
            ;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
            ;php_flag[display_errors] = off
            php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
            php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
            ;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M

            ; Set session path to a directory owned by process user
            php_value[session.save_handler] = files
            php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

nginx config:

```
        [root@localhost php-fpm.d]# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        # For more information on configuration, see:
        #   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
        #   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

        user nginx;
        worker_processes auto;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        pid /run/nginx.pid;

        # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
        include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

        events {
            worker_connections 1024;
        }

        http {
            log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

            sendfile            on;
            tcp_nopush          on;
            tcp_nodelay         on;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 550;
            keepalive_timeout   65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;

            include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type        application/octet-stream;

            # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
            # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
            # for more information.
            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

            server {
                listen       80 default_server;
                listen       [::]:80 default_server;
                server_name  _;
                root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                # Load configuration files for the default server block.
                include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

                location / {
                  try_files $uri /index.php index.php;
                }
                location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                }

                error_page 404 /404.html;
                    location = /40x.html {
                }

                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                    location = /50x.html {
                }
            }

        # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
        #
        #    server {
        #        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        #        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        #        server_name  _;
        #        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #
        #        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
        #        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
        #        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        #        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        #        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        #        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        #
        #        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        #        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        #
        #        location / {
        #        }
        #
        #        error_page 404 /404.html;
        #            location = /40x.html {
        #        }
        #
        #        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #            location = /50x.html {
        #        }
        #    }

        }
```

Comment: "php-fpm is run by php-fpm in which configuration is owned by nginx" This is not clear. If php-fpm is a user, don't expect it to have write permission on any file nginx:nginx where o-w.

Comment: @marekful php-fpm is a service that handles php requests.. it is not a user

Comment: As previously stated your FPM process is probably running under a different user from nginx... you need to check your fpm config file.  You should also make sure that your FPM user has read access to all of the parent folders in the tree.  Ex:  /root/webroot will be inaccessible if /root is 0700 even though /root/webroot is 0777.

Comment: @AlexBarker listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0776

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = nginx
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = nginx

Comment: @DemonSlayer That is not the correct configuration directive for changing the user and group of the FPM process.... that only changes the permissions of the unix socket that nginx talks to.... You are looking for the `user = www group = www`.  I am assuming the user and group you have referenced are in the httpd config not fpm. Its hard to tell what config your talking about.  Can you amend your post with the relative config details?  There should be 1 for nginx/apache CGI and one for the FPM process.

Comment: @AlexBarker edited please check post

Comment: @DemonSlayer I looked through it and aside from missing a group directive in Nginx, your configuration looks fine.  What file are you trying to write to? What is the ownership and permissions of the parent directories? Also are you using SELINUX?  Its enabled by default on RedHat and other distros.

Comment: What file are you trying to write to and what did you upgrade?

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570203/unix-installer-cant-find-path-to-file-even-though-im-entering-the-exact-path/29571473#29571473 may give an extra set of eyes to your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I cringed at `also in visudo I added this line`. Giving a user sudo access to all commands is a bad idea and is the wrong solution for problems with writing to a file. The only way that the sudoers file is relevant is if you are using the sudo command in your application. Instead, you need to look very carefully at permissions and ownership - it sounds like you are on the right track.

Comment: @millinon Vultr service was faulty for all servers after an unexpected shutdown happened to all their services, after switching to another service the script worked as it was supposed to