# gsl-2.2.1 won't allow me to remove folder

Tags: linux, permissions, root

I am a user on a large cluster computing server--i.e. I unequivocally do not have root privileges.

I routinely will install packages on my home directory (in a folder named `packages`), so I can more effectively perform version control (rather than leave it up to the system admin).

Normally I will compile from source, using the `--prefix=$HOME/packages` option when I run `./configure`. After I finish installing what I need to install, I'll delete the original folder.

I ran into an issue with [gsl-2.2.1](http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/gsl/). When I try to remove this folder using `rm -r gsl-2.2.1`, I get an error. for example:
`rm: cannot remove`gsl-2.2.1/cdf': Permission denied`

It turns out I can't even look into this folder (once again, saying "Permission denied"). I'm curious how these folders are 1) write protected against me--since I downloaded them in the first place, and 2) If there is a way to remove them without root privileges?

Or should I just ask the system admin to do it for me?

Thanks!

EDIT, as requested, this is what my packages directory looks like:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls $HOME/packages
bin  include  lib  man  openssl  R-3.3.1  share  var
```

gsl seems to have installed in the `include` and `bin` folders, e.g.:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -ld $HOME/packages/include/gsl/*
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 21934 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_blas.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1579 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_blas_types.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2290 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2417 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_complex_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2557 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2767 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_complex_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2185 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2325 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   580 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2255 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2535 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2290 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2325 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2373 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2338 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2373 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2408 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_block_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3849 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_bspline.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 33677 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_cblas.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7373 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_cdf.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4509 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_chebyshev.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1579 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_check_range.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2866 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_combination.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3374 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_complex.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6048 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_complex_math.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6232 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_const_cgs.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6779 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_const_cgsm.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1056 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_const.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7034 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_const_mksa.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6929 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_const_mks.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1761 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_const_num.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1564 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_deriv.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1854 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_dft_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1814 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_dft_complex.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2629 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_dht.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1558 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_diff.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 13274 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_eigen.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5965 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_errno.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5349 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4830 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft_complex.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1402 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3234 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft_halfcomplex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3028 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft_halfcomplex.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2382 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft_real_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2232 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fft_real.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2764 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_fit.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1454 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_heapsort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5642 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_histogram2d.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4140 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_histogram.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2715 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_ieee_utils.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2463 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_inline.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 10944 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_integration.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  8795 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_interp2d.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6961 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_interp.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 28064 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_linalg.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3805 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_machine.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4345 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_math.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12323 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12844 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 14076 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 15378 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 11363 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12550 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   598 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12096 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 13912 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12323 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12550 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12710 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12483 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12710 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12937 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_matrix_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2420 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_message.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4039 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_min.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2632 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_minmax.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2405 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_mode.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1601 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_monte.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2662 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_monte_miser.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1884 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_monte_plain.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3234 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_monte_vegas.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12230 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multifit.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12064 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multifit_nlinear.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 11357 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multifit_nlin.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5411 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multilarge.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 12990 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multilarge_nlinear.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6795 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multimin.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6152 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multiroots.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2784 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_multiset.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1335 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_nan.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2149 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_ntuple.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 13781 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7760 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_odeiv.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3346 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permutation.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1430 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1509 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_complex_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1515 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1563 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_complex_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1432 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1438 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   614 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1422 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1486 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1430 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1351 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1407 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_complex_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1414 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1456 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_complex_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1351 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1358 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   733 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1344 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1400 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1351 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1358 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1358 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1351 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1358 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1365 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_matrix_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1438 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1454 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1446 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1454 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1462 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1465 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1527 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_complex_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1546 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1600 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_complex_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1455 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1474 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   733 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1456 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1528 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1465 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1474 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1474 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1465 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1474 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1483 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_permute_vector_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5408 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_poly.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2301 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_pow_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1780 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_precision.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2355 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_qrng.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  9574 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_randist.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6957 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_rng.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3728 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_roots.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2836 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_rstat.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3709 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_airy.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 14165 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1467 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_clausen.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4402 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_coulomb.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4165 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_coupling.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1402 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_dawson.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2303 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_debye.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4171 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_dilog.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1657 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_elementary.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4159 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_ellint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1364 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_elljac.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2295 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_erf.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3847 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_exp.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4397 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_expint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3413 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_fermi_dirac.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7750 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2154 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_gegenbauer.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1040 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4517 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_hyperg.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2000 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_laguerre.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1813 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_lambert.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1 11891 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_legendre.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2062 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_log.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4307 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_mathieu.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1390 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_pow_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2683 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_psi.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1577 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_result.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1723 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_synchrotron.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1978 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_transport.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3957 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_trig.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2894 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sf_zeta.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3018 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_siman.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1974 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1967 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1995 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   435 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1953 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2121 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1974 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1995 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2075 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2054 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2075 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2096 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1878 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1817 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1900 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   533 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1856 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2032 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1878 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1900 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1916 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1894 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1916 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1938 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sort_vector_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1809 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_spblas.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   173 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_specfunc.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2489 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_splinalg.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4614 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_spline2d.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  2781 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_spline.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5599 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_spmatrix.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4681 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6802 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7003 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   519 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4605 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7729 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4681 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4757 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5085 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5009 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5085 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5161 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_statistics_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  5468 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sum.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1954 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_sys.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1850 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_test.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1149 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_types.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7346 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_char.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  8268 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_complex_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  9079 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_complex_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   764 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_complex.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  9967 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_complex_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  6791 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7492 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_float.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   598 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7200 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_int.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  8368 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_long_double.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7346 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_long.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7492 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_short.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7652 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_uchar.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7506 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_uint.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7652 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_ulong.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  7798 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_vector_ushort.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1   460 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_version.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  4183 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_wavelet2d.h
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ANON123 Group1  3043 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/include/gsl/gsl_wavelet.h
```

and

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -ld $HOME/packages/bin/gsl*
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 ANON123 Group1  1346 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/bin/gsl-config
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 ANON123 Group1  9862 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/bin/gsl-histogram
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 ANON123 Group1 25689 Sep  5 14:10 /Users/ANON123/packages/bin/gsl-randist
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to include what is returned by `ls -ld $HOME/packages/gsl-2.2.1/cdf` . Also see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26718467/620097 (not exactly your problem, but the explanation and diagnostic tips may help). Good luck.

Comment: do the values for user and Group in the `ls -ld` output look correct? If so, then it may be a parent dir perms are blocking you ability to change gsl-2.2.1/cdf. See my link in previous comment (a similar, but not identical problem). Good luck.